# R: Writing double summations in matrix form

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, linear-algebra

[image]

I would like to get rid of the summation over $t$ and implement that in R. So far, I have this

```
Z_diff = mapply(FUN = function(i) {Z-Z[i]}, i=1:n, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
rss = 0
for(t in 1:n){
    rss = rss + t(Y - X %*% B[,t]) %*% (diag(c(Z_diff[,t])) %*% (Y - X %*% B[,t]))
  }
```

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: @deschen How can I get rid of the summation over $t$ to avoid using the `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below we define a test input and compute the rss using the original formula in the question.  Then we show a matrix formula that gives the same result.  If you write out the formulas for the components of the matrix in the sum of the last line the reason for the result should be clear.

```
# input
set.seed(123)
n <- 4
Z <- rnorm(n)
Y <- rnorm(n)
B <- matrix(rnorm(n*n), n)
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*n), n)

# scalar sum
rss <- 0
for(i in 1:n) 
  for(t in 1:n) 
    rss <- rss + (Y[i] - c( crossprod(X[i, ], B[, t])))^2 * (Z[t] - Z[i])
rss
## [1] 43.39269

# matrix sum
ZZ <- t(outer(Z, Z, "-"))
sum(ZZ * (Y - X%*%B)^2)
## [1] 43.39269
```

### Performance

With the data above the matrix formulation runs about 300x faster on my machine.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
scalar = {
  rss <- 0
  for(i in 1:n) 
    for(t in 1:n) 
      rss <- rss + (Y[i] - c( crossprod(X[i, ], B[, t])))^2 * (Z[t] - Z[i])
  rss
},
matrix = {
  ZZ <- t(outer(Z, Z, "-"))
  sum(ZZ * (Y - X%*%B)^2)
})
+ })
## Unit: microseconds
##    expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval cld
##  scalar 34428.2 36966.35 44244.423 38257.80 40968.6 407679.6   100   b
##  matrix    80.8    82.45   148.764   156.45   177.8    721.7   100  a
```